# IEnumerable<int> Collection find sum and if it's divisible by 2

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I am new to C# programming and I'm not sure how to solve this problem. Was I supposed to put this code in the main and have the DivisibleByTwo method in another class???

Also, what exactly is an IEnumerable???

Problem: Create a function that takes a collection of integers as parameters. The function should then determine if the sum of the collection is divisible by 2 and return the result.

class SumDivisible
    {

```
    public bool DivisibleByTwo(IEnumerable<int>integerCollection)
    {
        int sum = 0;

        foreach (int integer in intCollection)
        {
            sum += integer;
        }

        if (sum % 2 == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You might want to use `long sum = 0` since the sum of ints can be greater than `int.MaxValue`.

Answer (score 0):

An `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>` is simply a collection that supports being enumerated *(iterated like through a* `foreach` *loop)*. In and of of itself it's just a specific interface -- the first being an untyped collection, the second being specifically typed (T is the type). Either can be used in places like `foreach' loops or using LINQ queries.

The problem itself doesn't say whether or not you should include it in a class. It simply says create a function (which you did). Here's an alternate version for the fun of it.

```
public bool IsEven(IEnumerable<int> source)
   => source.Sum() % 2 == 0;
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony! The lambda version is sweet!

Comment: @njia Please mark this as answered if my answer took care of your question.